# Nullpointer Acess message in Java

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception

I have created a method to parse a JSON object and to return an array of string.

```
private String[] getAttributesfromJson(JSONObject attacheddataattributejson) {
    String returnjsonArray[] = null;
    JSONArray subcatarray = attacheddataattributejson.optJSONArray("subcatAttributes");
    if(subcatarray!=null){
        for(int i=0;i<subcatarray.length();i++)
        {
            returnjsonArray[i]=subcatarray.getJSONObject(i).optString("name");
        }   
    }
    return returnjsonArray;
}
```

But my eclipse is showing an warning on returnjsonArray[i] that this can only be null at this pos. But I have a null check for subcatarray also. Please help.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

You initialize your `returnjsonArray[]` to `null` and try to access it without having ever initialized it.

Java does no magic with `null` references; what is more, arrays are *not* dynamically allocated in Java. If you want that, use a `List` (which you should initialize as well), and return this list's `.toArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

See this line

```
String returnjsonArray[] = null;
```

You forgot to initialize it.

You won't get anything from a basket when you did'nt fill it before.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code.

---

```
private String[] getAttributesfromJson(JSONObject attacheddataattributejson) throws JSONException {
        List<String> returnjsonArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONArray subcatarray = attacheddataattributejson.optJSONArray("subcatAttributes");
        if (subcatarray != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < subcatarray.length(); i++) {
                returnjsonArray.add(subcatarray.getJSONObject(i).optString("name"));
            }
        }
    return (String[]) returnjsonArray.toArray();
}
```